# Validate request host

Tags: java, rest

I'm developing a REST API, in some cases i want to make sure a request came from a known ip that set in a backend UI.
I tried this:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(allowedHostname);
    InetAddress[] allowedIps = InetAddress.getAllByName(url.getHost());
    for (InetAddress host : allowedIps) {
        if (requesterIp.equals(host.getHostAddress())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    logger.warn("[validateHostname] ", e);
}
return false;
```

Where allowedHostname = request.getRemoteAddr()

But it doesn't seems to work.
i do not want just to validate the hostname, because it is relatively easy to make requests in the name of another host.

**Edit**

requesterIp = request.getRemoteAddr()

allowedHostname = a predefined url set in backend UI

Answer (score 0):

Your serlvet container or appserver is most likely behind a proxy. To get the correct address you'll need to configure the proxy to forward the remote ip address.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

`String getRemoteAddr()`

> Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy that sent the request.